# Encode partial url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey,
i know it is easy, but for some reason, i just cant come up with the solution. i am using the facebook javascript sdk. I try to implement the paging feature. bascically, i can extract the url for the next objects with response.paging.next which gives me:

```
/me/home?access_token=blabla&limit=25&until=2011-01-17T00:30:42+0000
```

However, what i need to call this is:

```
/me/home?access_token=encodedblabla&limit=25&until=2011-01-17T00%3A38%3A15%2B0000
```

which can also be found in the rare json string.

it seems, when i call response.paging.next, the parser automatically decodes the url and i just cant seem to find a way to get the encoded url back. whenever i try to encode the whole url, obviously it is not an valid url anymore, so i guess i need to encode each parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am sure there is an easier way, but until then i used:

```
url.split('&callback=')[0]+'&limit=25&until='+encodeURIComponent(url.split('&until=')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Would Javascript's `escape` method do what you want?

```
var url = ""/me/home?access_token=blabla&limit=25&until=2011-01-17T00:30:42+0000"";
escape(url);
// --> "/me/home%3Faccess_token%3Dblabla%26limit%3D25%26until%3D2011-01-17T00%3A30%3A42+0000"
```